# Bug en input date en el administrador django con datepiker personalizado

Tags: django, datepicker, django-admin

Un saludo para todos.

Estoy trabajando sobre un proyecto de Django, el cual realiza todos sus procesos sobreescribiendo metodos y templates de Django Admin.

Uno de los puntos a cambiar es el datepiker por default que trae el administrador de django ya que no es practico para buscar fechas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por esta razón estuve investigando y construí una clase modificador para el date piker de la siguiente forma

```
from django import forms

class CustomDatePikerWidget(forms.DateInput):

    DATE_INPUT_WIDGET_REQUIRED_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d'

    def __init__(self, attrs={}, format=None):
        attrs.update(
            {
                'class': 'form-control',
                'type': 'date',
            }
        )
        self.format = format or self.DATE_INPUT_WIDGET_REQUIRED_FORMAT
        super(CustomDatePikerWidget, self).__init__(attrs, format=format)
```

Ya con esta clase puedo sobreescribir el datepiker pasandola como valor al atributo formfield_overrides del ModelAdmin Persona

```
@admin.register(Persona)
class PersonaAdmin(BaseImportExportModelAdmin):

    formfield_overrides = {
        models.DateField: {'widget': CustomDatePikerWidget},
    }
```

Lo cual se ve genial y funciona mejor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo cuando ingreso a editar a la persona no me muestra (no se visualiza) la fecha guardada, pero si esta el dato en value del html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede evidencia el valor se guarda y calcula la edad. Pero no se ve en el input de fecha de nacimiento para este caso.

Quien me pueda colaborar con alguna información para solucionar este tema les agradezco.

Comment: por lo que se puede ver uno es mm/dd/yy pero en el original es dd/mm/yy

Comment: yo hace tiempo tuve un problema similar, el cual surgia que manejaba zona horaria mexico y la bd (mariadb) no tenia dada de alta las zonas, y con un [script](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7iwL5F-hwr_dWdjTDREcXNHQmM/view?resourcekey=0-8MlAO0NfRRQ48xmSzsH9YA) para dar de alta las zonas horarias lo solucione.

Comment: ¿Cómo estás definiendo ese campo de fecha de nacimiento en tu form? Fijate además, como te indicaron en el comentario anterior, que en el campo se muestra el formato 'mm/dd/yyyy', pero en el valor se muestra 'dd/mm/yyyy'.

Comment: Estoy usando postgresql como motor de base de datos, la zona horaria la defino en la configuración de Django y el sistema operativo en windows 10 para local y linux en el sevidor

Comment: No estoy usando froms, ya que trabajo con una interfan completamente sobre el admind de django, lo que hago es sobre escribir los metodos y atributos de 
`djanngo.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin`

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema. ¿Pudiste solucionarlo? Gracias!